# Is there a way to make my own onevent handler for a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

for example, I am trying to make something like this:

```
connection = new WorkshopConnect(thisWorkshopID);

    connection.onopen = function (evt) {
        log(`connection.onopen:`, evt);
    };
```

Where I can call a class and then call an event handler with the class property, and then when a certain event happens within the class. It will fire the onopen property, which will then call the function it is attached to.

I hope I explained it in a way you can understand.

Comment: Are you looking for [`CustomEvent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)? See [Creating and triggering events](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! There are many ways of acomplishing this. The easiest way (in my opinion) is to create a class such as this:

```js
class EventEmitter {
    emit(event, ...args) {
        const handler = this['on' + event];
        if (typeof handler == 'function') {
            handler(...args);
        }
    }
}
```

Then extend the class and call the event when necessary:

```js
class Class extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        setTimeout(this.emit.bind(this), 1e3, 'ready');
    }
}
```

And finally, listen for the event.

```js
const instance = new Class();
instance.onready = function() {
    console.log('Ready!');
}
```

If you want a proper EventEmitter with this included, it wouldn't be too hard to implement into the EventEmitter class. Hope it helps!

Comment: The standard [`EventTarget`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) (which is subclassable), [`dispatchEvent`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), etc. already exist. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @SebastianSimon but aren't those for HTML/DOM elements/constructors? I assumed the question was just for objects in general. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, well, in a Web environment these can be used for anything. I just realized that the OP might not work in a Web environment. Your suggestion isn’t wrong, I just meant that a standard API for this already exists and we should use the standard, whenever possible.

Comment: Wow! thank you, yes! this is exactly what I was looking for! I do have one more question. How can I pass arguments within the event?

Comment: Nevermind, I figure out how to do it. setTimeout(this.emit.bind(this), 1e3, 'ready',<place argument here>);. Thank you again!

Comment: @JayHandle you're welcome! But please keep in mind that the timeout is only there to simulate a promise for the example. When you emit an event, you won't want to have the 'setTimeout' every time you emit an event; or any time, for that matter.